# How to keep the scrolling position when adding a new elements in the top using ListView or CustomScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to add new elements into the top of the ListVeiw or CustomScrollView and keep the scroll position as it's with Flutter

I've tried the following

```
extentAfter = _scrollController.position.extentAfter;
_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - extentAfter);
```

but this won't work well with SliverAppBar - floating and its actually not optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the cleanest way would be to add those items only when user scrolls back to the top of the ListView. You can cache them in memory for the moment user is far enough from the top (in your case) of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much, if (_scrollController.position.pixels == 0.0) {
               //toDo
              }

Comment: I don't understand this.. could you kindly add a code example or any better implementation?